# Which Rav was this?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, gezel-stealing, story-identification

I heard a rabbi tell a famous true story of a certain other rabbi.  A black man broke into his house in the middle of the night and demanded at gunpoint all of the rabbi’s money/valuables. The rabbi confronted him and asked him what was wrong in his life that sunk him to this level. The man broke down crying and told the rabbi. Years later, at the rabbi’s funeral, a black man was seen crying bitterly over the deceased. This was the would-be robber, whom the rabbi had influenced to do “teshuvah” (to return to the straight-and-narrow). Does anyone know the name of the rabbi in this true story?

Answer (score 2):

The Rabbi he was referring to  was probably   Rabbi Meir Feist

see this link for more about him and the story (in a slightly different version)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/rabbi-meir-feist-ztl-paradigm-strength-tzidkus-honor-his-yosef-gesser

It doesn't mention the funeral part but  that was always part of the story. In  most versions I heard the story starts with his funeral and the black man crying being asked why he came at all. Conversely this is the first time I'm seeing that he "directed him to a professional who helped him turn his life around" In the versions I'm familiar  with  he found the thief  a job and helped him turn his life around himself